# How do I add arbitrary metadata to a .dae export?

Tags: python, scripting, export, import, collada

I am assuming that a basic python script can be written to achieve this. I am trying to add some information packed into my exported .dae that will include an UUID for use in an external application. My best guess right now is that I can use an "extra" tag somehow, like Blender uses for importing/exporting scene lights set up in Blender. I am going to be using this repeatedly for many exported files.
Thanks for any help you can provide! Let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 1):

The collada support built into blender is done using C++ code. I would suggest getting this [collada-exporter addon](https://github.com/godotengine/collada-exporter) and adjusting it to add in your extra data. You will need to look through the [collada specs](https://www.khronos.org/collada/) to see how an extra tag would be acceptable within the file format.

Unless you calculate the tag as you go, you can add a [custom property](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html) to the object type to store the tag info, then use that in the export steps. You would define that in the addons `register()`

```
def register():
    bpy.types.Object.mytag = bpy.props.StringProperty()
```